# IllegalStateException in Android MediaPlayer execution

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to run beeb sound continuously until user pressed the button. I added alarm.mp3 file to `raw folder`. But this media file not executing. I'm getting `IllegalStateException`.

This is my code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try{
            mp.release();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm);

            mp.prepare();
            mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start(); 

        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            System.out.println("Test Exception "+e);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Test Exception "+e);
        }
```

I added that mp3 file to `asset folder` and try to play it but still I'm getting same exception.

This is the code I used:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try{
                mp.release();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd=context.getAssets().openFd("alarm.mp3s");   
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start(); 

            }catch(IllegalStateException e){
                System.out.println("Test Exception "+e);

            }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Test Exception "+e);
            }
```

Any help would be appriciated. If you need more information please let me know.

**UPDATE:**

```
try{
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.alarm);
                mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start(); 

            }catch(IllegalStateException e){
                System.out.println("Test Exception "+e);

            }
```

When user click the button:

```
mp.stop();
         if(!mp.isPlaying()){
              mp.release();
         }
```

This is the exception:

```
10-04 12:50:06.105: I/System.out(14074): Test Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Comment: Once `release()` has been called `MediaPlayer` cannot be used. Call the method when you're completely done with `MediaPlayer` and its resources are no longer needed.

Comment: log and post the _full_ stacktrace, not just that short line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing stacktrace, it´s just an assumption. But you are directly calling

```
mp.release();
```

just after you have created one. The second is you are creating the `mediaPlayer` with `new MediaPlayer()` **AND** with `create()`. You don´t need `new MediaPlayer()` if you use `create()` and with `mp.create()` method, you don´t need to call `prepare()`. I would try it like this:

```
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm);            
  mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
  mp.setLooping(true);
  mp.start();
```

And just call `release` if mediaPlayer is finished. Like described in the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()), after `release()`, the `MediaPlayer` is in the end state:

> Once the MediaPlayer object is in the End state, it can no longer be
>   used and there is no way to bring it back to any other state.

You should follow the API, I know it´s much to read, but it´s very important to know all the stuff about the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I did changes you suggested but still I'm getting same Exception.

Comment: then please edit the posted code and please post your stacktrace and point out the line where the error occurs.

Comment: I updated the question.It is difficult to get the whole stack trace I'm working on a big project and couldn't find relevant part.

Comment: Ok, but it´s very important to see the relevant part of the stacktrace because here we can see the cause of the error and the part where it happens. From your updated code, it seems to be ok. So there must be any wrong call between...

Comment: and you should clean your project and deinstall it from your device. That is also often a problem. old version stays on the device and it´s not correctly updated.

Comment: I'm trying to get the relevant part. It's running without stop. I will try to get it somehow and let you know.

Comment: one additional info: In your try/catch statement, please add `e.printStacktrace()`, so you will get the full error log.

Comment: yes, it solved. Your answer helped me. Thanks for that.